# Crystal Reports printoptions not working on asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

Simple .NET 4.0 application that just opens an rpt. I just want to force Landscape and A4 paper and i cant make it work.

I tried removing the printer from page setup in report design but no luck.

Source:

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfigureCrystalReports();
        }
        private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
        {
            //
            ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            //
            ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Properties.Settings.Default.rptPath));
            rptDoc.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;
            rptDoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperA4;
            //
            myConnectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;
            myConnectionInfo.UserID = "xxxxx";
            myConnectionInfo.Password = "xxxxx";
            //
            crViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            //
            SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);
        }
```

Comment: Are you printing client-side via the viewer, or doing it server-side?

Comment: client side by the viewer in the aspx page

Comment: Did you design the .rpt as landscape (Design -> Page Setup: Orientation)?

Comment: @nunzabar: Yes and i tried with or without a printer in page setup in CR designer